# Connecting different lipo in series to achive high voltage

Tags: lipo, capacity, lithium-ion

I'm not so familiar with lipo and liion but know their dangers.

For my recent project I got an audio amplifier which works well on voltage of 14-18V so I need this range of voltage.
My amplifier is portable so I have little storage for batteries so I chose lipo and liion as they have good weight to power ratio but I dont have same capacity batterys for this.
I have 6 1250 mah liion and 1 3500mah lipo and now the problem starts.

1. I have small 1s protection circuit.  Can I connect it to 2p3s for 1250 mah liion (1 circuit/2cell i.e 3 circuit in series?)
2. Can I connect this above setup if possible with my lipo which has its own protection circuit (mobile battery) which gives voltage of approx 16.8v in total (in theory.)
3. I have a BMS from China which is not actually the BMS I saw video on youtube for it from greatscott and concluded it is just a protection circuit so I designed this my own circuit please help to figure out if it works:

[image]

Comment: As a general rule you should not use cells of different capacity in a battery, particularly with a potentially self igniting chemistry like lipo. The protection circuit may take care of the undercharge/overcharge issues but I would not rely on that.

Comment: Very ideally don't combine LiPo and LiIon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect cells with different capacities in series **if you handle intelligently the fact that they have different capacities**, by charging them separately perhaps, and by detecting the end point voltage on all cells individually. This would mean you always had to charge it like a lab experiment, rather than an easy-to-use battery.

If you connect cells of different capacity to a standard BMS that is expecting cells of the same nominal capacity, then you could confuse it. What it would actually do, faced with different capacity cells, depends on its software, what it's been programmed to do, how clever it's supposed to be.

In the best case, it would take excess time during charging keeping all the cells at the same voltage. It would have to charge the capacity difference at low current through the cell voltage monitor lines, rather than at high current through the battery terminals.

In the worst case, it would declare that there was a larger than threshhold diffference in capacity between the cells and so think the lower capacity cells were broken, and refuse to work.

Re-reading your question, I note that you also want to use different types of lithium, a mix of LiPo and LIon. The latter use slightly lower voltages. I doubt that you will find any BMS that can be set up to mix the two types. While calling them all LIon is conservative for charging, you would need to call them all LiPo to be conservative for end voltage. You can still charge, and monitor discharge manually, on a cell by cell basis.

Comment: Yeah, mixing different battery types is generally a bad idea and not worth the hassle, risk and bad performance.